# Where not null for reference column showing error - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to query a table where multiple referenced column in not null.

I tried like this:
    JobTypePresetting.where('comment_text == ?', nil)
    JobTypePresetting.where('comment_text_id == ? OR part_listing_id == ?', nil, nil)

Even first is not working showing error like

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer == unknown
LINE 1: ...resettings"."template_id" = $2 AND (comment_text_id == NULL)
                                                           ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How do i query this, currently i'm using like

```
JobTypePresetting.where('comment_text_id is not null or part_listing_id is not null')
```

Comment: You want a single equals sign, not a double.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single(=) oprator.

JobTypePresetting.where('comment_text = ?', nil)

Hope this may work for you.

Comment: You may also use

JobTypePresetting.where('comment_text IS NULL') 

OR

JobTypePresetting.where(comment_text: nil )

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Arel, much easier to construct complex sql queries. They have been part of rails from 3 release. https://github.com/rails/arel

```
jtp = JobTypePresetting.arel_table
JobTypePresetting.where(jtp[:comment_text_id].not_eq(nil).or(jtp[: part_listing_id].not_eq(nil)))
```

Hope it helps